# Is there any secuirty risk to let a seller save the merchant ID by his own?

Tags: reactjs, paypal, payment-gateway

I've some questions about the Merchant ID that I can use in react-paypal-js.

If there is a buyer on my platform will the money go 100% without a cut to the merchant?

And is there any security risk to let the merchant save his ID with a form to my DB and store it there. Should it be crypted or is it anyway a public id and there is no problem someone sees this ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's public like a client ID. There is no risk, they simply identify the account receiving the payment.

The merchant will receive a normal PayPal payment, which will credit their account with the whole amount minus any credit card and PayPal processing fees, which vary by country.